# In python, how can I read a file stored in a database instead filesystem and use it as parameter on Popen

Tags: python

I am running a command from python using subprocess Popen. Command has a parameter to indicate the path to the file it will use. That file can only be specified via that parameter.

The command would be something like:

```
command -file /path/to/file
```

I cannot do something like:

```
cat /path/to/file | command -file
```

The problem is that I have that file in a database, which I read it from my python app. I would like to avoid having to save temporarily the file to disk and specify it in the command.

Is there any way to pipe that file in memory to Popen as argument for that parameter?

Thanks!

EDIT:
Ok, I should have specified the command and the code, but I did not have it at that moment.
I am trying to do an ocsp request for a certificate using openssl. I know there is an openssl module for python, but I want to avoid extra python modules.

This is the python code:

```
openssl = '/path/to/openssl'
ossl = subprocess.Popen([openssl, 'ocsp', '-no_cert_verify', '-issuer', 'cacert.cer', '-serial', '0x1234', '-url', url], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
```

I have cacert.cer stored in a database. I have not seen anyway to pass a piped argument to -issuer and I was hoping that there was any way to pipe it somehow using subprocess.PIPE

Comment: I'm not really clear. You want to read a file in the DB and use those parameters for your python code? Perhaps posting actual code would help.

Comment: Are you sure the command reads the file only once through sequentially? If it does multiple passes of the file or tries to seek, you will probably have to create a temporary.

Comment: I've edited the post to make it clearer.

Comment: @Karl: did we help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the command, as you are saying, expects a *path to a file in the file system* in order to operate on certain data, then there is only one way to provide it with such data: *have a file in the file system*. If that file does not exist yet, because the data is in the database and not in an individual file, then by all means of logic, you have to create that file before invoking that command. Note, however, that there are certain tricks, especially on POSIX-compliant systems, to create such files in an efficient fashion. One of these tricks was mentioned by skyjur.

Answer (score 0):

If it's unix you can use named pipe. It works like pipe but uses path on filesystem.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.mkfifo

1. Create fifo using `os.mkfifo()`
2. Start Popen and pass the fifo path as an argument
3. Write the content from database into fifo

Don't forget to do `.close()` on the opened fifo file, otherwise the process started with `Popen()` will never know where is the end of file.

Comment: Note that this approach will only work if the program reads through the file only once. If it does two passes of the file, or tries to seek in it, this will not work.

Comment: Great note @chthonicdaemon!